# calling aspx.cs method from javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, json, visual-studio-2010

I am currently trying to call a method in the aspx.cs inside of my javascript.

Below is what i currently have:

Javascript:

```
function loadPins(passValue) {
    callServer2("myMethod", passValue);
}

function callServer2(requestMethod, clientRequest) {
var pageMethod = "Default.aspx/" + requestMethod;

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: clientRequest,
    dataType: 'JSON',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: pageMethod , //Method to call 
    success: function (result, status) {
        alert("success");
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        alert("ERROR");
    }
  });
}
```

My `aspx.cs`:

```
 [WebMethod]
 public static string myMethod(string passedVal)
 {
     value = passedVal;
     return "true";
 }
```

When I debug I see it calling and entering `CallServer2` but it never seems to hit my break point in my aspx. I dont see my sucess or error message alerts either.

Any suggestions?

Error I am Currently Getting:

```
error - <html>
        <head>
        <title> Unknow we method myMethod.<br>Parameter name:
     methodName</title>
     <style>
      body{font-family:verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:
      .7em;color:black}
             p
     {font-family:"Verdana";font-weightbold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
b{font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
H1{
font-family:"veranda";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;colour:red}
H2{
font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal ;font-size:14pt color:maroon}
pre{font-family:"Lucida Console";font-size .9em}
.marker{font-weight:bold;color:black;text-decoration:none;}
.version{color:gray;}
.error{margin-bottom:10px}
.expandable{text-decoration:underline, font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand;}
</style>
<head>

<code>
An unhanded exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.</code>
...
```

***Note** I didnt put the ... thats really all it says after the line above

Comment: Can your debug go thru the server function, if not check the code again, your path must be wrong..

Comment: Can you also show the update $.ajax function..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.ajax({ type: "POST", 
        url: pageMethod, contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: "{passedVal:" + JSON.stringify(clientRequest) + "}", dataType: "json",
         success: function (result, status) {
        alert("success");
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        alert("ERROR");
    }

    });
```

you should pass data with passedVal in data, and do stringify your variable. Hope this helps..

Comment: is there something else I need to do? I got a really long error that looked like html code

Comment: im using visual studio with IE so i'm able to step through the program. i'll post the error in my question since its so long if thats okay with you

Comment: i have posted the error. I get the error at the very end after the program goes through all the jquery

Answer (score 0):

1. The [ScriptManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.aspx) should be on your page.
2. The [ScriptManager.EnablePageMethods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.enablepagemethods.aspx) should be set to true.

Also try changing your this line like this:

```
 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you have this in your clientRequest

```
data: "{'passedVal':'" + your_data+ "'}",
```

Hope this help you!